# Is it possible to produce circular (round) shaped radar chart in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I plot a standard Chart.js radar chart, the axis is a polygon shape (not round). [For example](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/radar.html):

[image: example of radar area chart with incorrect axis]

Is it possible to make the axis round shaped, [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/raw/21746a9668ffdf6d8242/)?:

[image: example of radar area chart with correct axis]

Comment: afaik, no. What you can do is "smoth" like the example you gaved

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit [2021-10-27]:** [Chart.js v3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html) has removed `scale` option in favor of `options.scales.r`. Here's an updated way of making the radar grid circular.

```js
const red = "rgb(255, 99, 132)";
const color = Chart.helpers.color;
const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [['Eating', 'Dinner'], ['Drinking', 'Water'], 'Sleeping', ['Designing', 'Graphics'], 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My dataset',
      backgroundColor: color(red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: red,
      pointBackgroundColor: red,
      data: [
        80,
        90,
        60,
        65,
        78,
        97,
        55
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: { // <-- Note change in options from scale to scales
        r: {
          grid: {
             circular: true
          },
          beginAtZero: true
        }
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function () {
  window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

**Edit:** Kudos to [@timclutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3775731/timclutton) for pointing to the [axes styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html?h=circular) section of the docs, which lists the `circular` property for the radar chart.

**Original answer:** After some digging it turned out that it is in fact possible. The trick is to add `scale: { gridLines: { circular: true } }` to `options` of the chart. Please see the snippet below. **Note.** As of 19 Jul 2019 I couldn't find this information in [the official docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html). So, it's either not documented yet or this feature might be changed / removed in future.

[image: chart.js circular / round shaped radar chart]

```js
const red = "rgb(255, 99, 132)";
const color = Chart.helpers.color;
const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: [['Eating', 'Dinner'], ['Drinking', 'Water'], 'Sleeping', ['Designing', 'Graphics'], 'Coding', 'Cycling', 'Running'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My dataset',
      backgroundColor: color(red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
      borderColor: red,
      pointBackgroundColor: red,
      data: [
        80,
        90,
        60,
        65,
        78,
        97,
        55
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        circular: true
      },
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function () {
  window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), config);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah, well done! I looked through the docs as well but couldn't see an option even though it made sense for there to be one as Chart.js can do it for the polar area chart! +1 :)

Comment: ..And of course searching for "circular" [finds it in the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html?h=circular) :)

Comment: Is there any similar code for 3.2 version? because this is not working

Answer (score 5):

Since [Version 3](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html), the scale option has been deprecated.
So to make the radar chart with circle gridlines, you have to pass the following option:

```
scales: {
  r: {
    grid: {
      circular: true,
    },
  },
},
```

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('radar-chart');

const data = {
  labels: [
    'Eating',
    'Drinking',
    'Sleeping',
    'Designing',
    'Coding',
    'Cycling',
    'Running'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
  }, {
    label: 'My Second Dataset',
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        grid: {
          circular: true,
        },
      },
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        borderWidth: 3
      }
    }
  },
};

const radarChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to change line tension:

```
data:{
        labels: ['visionary', 'determination', 'extraversion', 'agreeableness', 'emotionality'],
        datasets: [{
          data: [
            34, 45, 67, 89, 22
          ],          
          label: 'me',
          lineTension: 0.5,
          borderColor: '#00ffff',
          backgroundColor: '#00ffff',
         
    }
```

Then your radar charts will be rounded just as you showed in the desired fashion

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you are looking for; Chart.js [documents](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html) a [Polar area chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/polar.html) on it's [samples](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/) page:

[image: polar area chart example]

A quick example:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 20, 30]
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for response @timclutton. Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for.