# Chart.js v3.2 Change Radar background shape from Polygonal-Triangle to Circular

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have the following code rendering a triangular Radar chart with `Chart.js 3.2`

```
const twoWeeksSentimentSummaryRadar = new Chart(twoWeeksSentimentSummaryRadarCtx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: [
          'Positive',
          'Neutral',
          'Negative'
        ],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Sentiment',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(182,198,255,0.26)',
          borderColor: '#B6C6FF',
          borderWidth: 3,
          data: [curWeekPositiveSum, curWeekNeutralSum, curWeekNegativeSum]
        }]
    },
    options: {
            plugins: {
            legend: {
            display: false
          }
        },
        scales: {
            r: {
                ticks: {
                    maxTicksLimit: 6,
                    font: {
                    family: 'Helvetica Neue',
                    style: 'normal',
                    weight: 'normal',
                    size: 8,
                    lineHeight: '100%'
                  },
                  color: '#A6AAC2'
                },
                pointLabels: {
                    font: {
                    family: 'Helvetica Neue',
                    style: 'normal',
                    weight: 500,
                    size: 14,
                    lineHeight: '100%'
                  },
                  color: '#1C1C1C'
                }
            }
        }
    }
  });
```

[image]

How can I convert it's background shape to be circular like the chart below?

There is a similar ticket [Is it possible to produce circular (round) shaped radar chart in Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188029/is-it-possible-to-produce-circular-round-shaped-radar-chart-in-chart-js/57198398) but if I am understanding correctly the solution is compatible with previous version

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the options you can set the grid to circular:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    r: {
      grid: {
        circular: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        grid: {
          circular: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was so stupid that i tried scale and not scales! can you additionally tell me if there are other scales except from r in radar chart.js?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Do you know if is there is an option to change the background of this circular area??