# Recharts: Make edges of the radar to be rounded

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to create a radar chart in recharts but I need the edges of the radar to be rounded.

The chart provided looks like this:
[image]

while I need to make it look like this:

[image]

Comment: this might b helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57188029/is-it-possible-to-produce-circular-round-shaped-radar-chart-in-chart-js

Comment: Thanks for your insight, but I need it in recharts

Answer (score 0):

if you want a radar with circle type radar instead of the polygon, update the `PolarGrid` element and set the **gridType** prop to "circle"

```
<PolarGrid gridType="circle" />
```

The default is "polygon"

[image: Circle Radar]

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-radar-chart-circle-type-cr3rnl

Entire code:

```
<RadarChart
      cx={300}
      cy={250}
      outerRadius={150}
      width={500}
      height={500}
      data={data}
    >
      <PolarGrid gridType="circle" />
      <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="subject" />
      <PolarRadiusAxis />
      <Radar
        name="Mike"
        dataKey="A"
        stroke="#8884d8"
        fill="#8884d8"
        fillOpacity={0.6}
      />
</RadarChart>
```